# Where to get the html directory of an aspx page, if there is no <contentLink> tag?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How can I get the HTML page behind the aspx page of SharePoint?

Normally, if I open the aspx code, there is a `<contentlink>` tag from where I can get the webpart directory. As I am new to Sharepoint development, when I need to edit something on the HTML, I got the directory link from the `<contentLink>` tag. But in a particular case, there is no such tag on an aspx file. Where can I find the HTML content of that particular page so that I can edit it?